# How can I overlap an img on top of another one in ionic

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to create something similar to this:

[image]

in my design, but I'm not sure what CSS to use in ionic. This is what my code sample looks like

```html
<ion-item class="main-container" lines="none">
    <ion-img class="cover-img"
      src="../../assets/images/logo.png"
    ></ion-img>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item class="main-container" lines="none" style="margin:0;">
      <ion-avatar>
        <img src="../../assets/images/avatar.png" />
      </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>Item Avatar</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

Can anyone help me with the CSS part?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin-top: -50px` to achieve that.

Also you can make it a `position: absolute` element and use `top: -50px` or `top: -50%` too.

Red example is with `position: absolute` and black one is with `margin`:

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div style="width: 45%; height: 100px; margin-top: 50px; margin-right: 5%; border: 1px solid black">
    <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: -25px 0 0 25px; border: 1px solid black"></div>
  </div>

  <div style="position: relative; width: 45%; height: 100px; margin-top: 50px; border: 1px solid red">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 50px; top: -50%; right: 50%; transform: translate(50%, 50%); border: 1px solid red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first option worked (only half was showing) but it was behind the cover img and the second option didn't work.

Comment: second works if you give position reletive to the bottom container. and the first one will be ok if you set a `z-index` for it. like `z-index: 5`. the banner must have a lower `z-index`. @crystalWitchEla

Comment: see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp to learn more about `position: absolute`.

Comment: I added a snippet to explain better. @crystalWitchEla